# Root-Relative URLs not working

Tags: google-app-engine

I just moved my website to a custom domain in GAE. But when I'm in the website in the new domain, the root-relative URLs are pointing to *.appspot.com. As a result, I would like to know if root-relative URLs work on GAE. If so, someone knows how to make them work?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by root-relative URLs? You could show some examples, or, better yet, snippets of code building and referencing them.

Comment: Relative URLs work. In your case either of the following could be true: 1) Your custom domain is not properly configured (does not use CNAME) but a frame/proxy of some kind. 2) Your internal links (hrefs) contain the domain / are not really relative 3) You  have a `<base href="...">`-tag set (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp). (... many more possible reasons ...)

Comment: @DanCornilescu What I mean is that the link /account in the html is being generated as *.appspot.com/account instead of customdomain.com/account . Thus, is making my website links inaccessible. konqi I created the custom domain using A records. Thats something that is interfering?

Comment: @matheus: you need to provide more info about how are you building your URLs, maybe show how the resulting HTML code looks like, etc.